# EF Core: update database error: column "PostalCode" of relation "City" already exists [PostgreSQL]

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class and in this class there is "PostalCode"

```
public string CityName { get; set; }
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
```

I'm creating a migration

```
add-migration AddPostalCode
```

Then I update the database

```
update-database
```

Error:

```
42701: column "PostalCode" of relation "City" already exists
```

Because PostalCode was added manually to the City table in the database.

Not only PostalCode, there are other manually added fields.
How do I update the database by ignoring these fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EF 6**

If you have an existing schema then you should create a snapshot of it with

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
```

Then add your changes to the models i.e. add your `PostalCode` to the model then add the migration and update:

```
Add-Migration AddPostalCode
Update-Database
```

**EF Core**

If you're using EF Core then `-IgnoreChanges` is not an available parameter, you need to create an initial migration with an empty `Up()` method and apply it to create a baseline snapshot :

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

Add your changes to your model class i.e. add the `PostalCode` to your model. Then add a new migration for the changes and apply it:

```
Add-Migration AddPostalCode
Update-Database
```

Comment: i'm getting an error:
 A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IgnoreChanges'.

Comment: `IgnoreChanges` parameter is not available in EF core, see my edit

Comment: didn't work for me after creating the "InitialCreate" migration I get the error "-relation 'Categories' already exists" when creating my first table without reaching the City table

Comment: Did you remove all the code inside the InitialCreate migration `Up()` method?

Comment: yes, I created a migration "add-migration InitialCreate" then I remove all code inside the InitialCreate migration Up(). Then I run "database-update".   Then I created another migration "add-migration AddPostalCode" but in this migration the Up() method is also empty.

Comment: The second migration should have your new postal code column in the `Up()` changes. The first migration assumes you haven't added the `PostalCode` to your model yet, this needs to not be added yet or it will add it to your baseline snapshot so the 2nd migration will be empty. So ideally you remove any current changes (i.e. remove PostalCode from your model) create an initial migration with an empty `Up()` and apply it then add the `PostalCode` to your model and create a new migration which should have the changes in its `Up()` then apply it

Answer (score 0):

You can either delete the postal code column from the table directly it is assigned too

or

go into your migration that was created from add-migration AddPostalCode and remove the code from the Up section that adds the PostalCode column to the table.

However you should NOT be adding table columns manually to a DB, so if its possible go and delete that column from the DB and let your code first approach be the only way you add columns.
Its really bad practice to manually add columns when using EF and code first approach.